# Greenplum installation error

Tags: greenplum

While installing greenplum we are getting below error after running gpcheck command

GPCHECK_ERROR : uname -r output is different among hosts.

on two machines we have installed centos6 and in one machine we have installed centos7.

for greenplum installation is it necessary all hosts should have same os version?
should we ignore this error and go ahead.?

Answer (score 2):

You must have the same OS version on all the cluster machines. Greenplum home directory is used for installing gppkgs (add-ons) that are in fact packed rpms. Greenplum initializes rpm database inside of GPDB home directory for managing add-ons. Whenever you do "gpseginstall" (installation, expansion), GPDB copies the content of GPDB home directory to other hosts. However RPM database created on one version of OS is not valid on another, so you would get errors trying to install/list/remove packages there

In general, if you don't plan to use any gppkgs and use it merely for PoC purposes, this should work, but I would strongly recommend to use the same OS version on all the cluster hosts

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to have same OS (kernel). If it is not production environment you can give try ignoring it. I have never tested it.